# JQuery use .offset to scroll down to CSS class + extra pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple jQuery if statement that immediately scrolls down to a section with the class 'registration' once the page is loaded. That works, but I need it to have it go another 156px more due to the sticky header. Otherwise, the top portion of the section won't be visible.

Page in question: https://acumedstaging.wpengine.com/registration

This is what I currently have:

```
if(top.location.pathname === '/registration/'){
 $('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(".registration").offset({ top: 156 })
 });
}
```

I've tried some other methods with .offset as well but no luck so far. Any idea how to make this function.... function?

Comment: could you provide testable demo ?

Comment: Yes, I'll place it in the overall copy above.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the correct way to use `.offset()`, what this code is actually trying to do is set the offset of the elements matched by `.registration`:

```js
$(".registration").offset({ top: 156 })
```

`.offset()` with no arguments returns an object which looks like `{top: 400, left: 25}` which represents the offset of the element.

Instead use:

```js
$(".registration").offset().top + 156 + 'px'
```

Comment: I actually tried something like that but it's still ignoring the +156 and just scrolling to the top of the registration div.

Comment: You can try: ( +$(".registration").offset().top + 156 ) + "px"